# Prove correctness for this lcm iterative program

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, induction

Studying for finals, trying to solve this problem:

> Given positive integers $n$ and $m$, we say that $m$ is a multiple of $n$ iff there is some $k \in N$ such that $m = kn$.
>
> For positive integers $a$, $b$, we define the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, denoted $lcm(a, b)$, to be the smallest number that is both a multiple of $a$ and a multiple of $b$.
>
> Prove that the following program is correct with respect to its given specification.
>
> Precondition: $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.
>
> Postcondition: Return $lcm(a, b)$.

```
lcm(a, b)
x=a; y=b 
while x \= y:
    if x < y: 
        x=x+a
    else: 
        y=y+b
return x
```

My loop invariant so far:
For $k \in N$, define $P(k)$ as such:
$P(k)$: if $a$, $b$ are positive integers and the loop iterates at least $k$ times, then:

1. $x_k \ge a$ and $y_k \ge b$
2. $x_k$ is a multiple of $a$ and $y_k$ is a multiple of $b$
3. $x_k \le ab$

I'm not sure if my LI is correct. I'm having a hard time proving the last one (#3) in my induction step and not really sure how to prove partial correctness either (I'm taking the approach of LI + exit condition implies post condition).

Any suggestions please?

Comment: what does it mean "while x /= y:" ?

Comment: x != y. I edited it to fix the format, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b > 1$, we know that $a,b < ab$. Your algorithm adds positive number to either $x$ or $y$, in each step. That means that in each step exactly one of this values grows, so - at one point - you'll get one of these:

1. $x \ge ab$, $y < ab$; or
2. $x < ab$, $y \ge ab$; or
3. $x = y$.

Since you worry about $\le ab$, let us assume 1: $x \ge ab$, $y < ab$. Notice that $x = ab$. If this wasn't the case, we'd have $x - b \ge ab$, so the last step wouldn't enlarge $x$ and its value wouldn't get $>ab$, which is a contradiction.

So, $x = ab$, $y < ab = x$.

As long as $y < x$, the algorithm will keep on adding $b$ to $y$. So, your $y$ will be getting values $y_0, y_0 + b, \dots, y_0 + kb$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ($y_0$ denotes the value that $y$ had when $x$ reached $ab$).

Now, same as with $x$: if $y_0 + kb > ab$, then $y_0 + (k-1)b \ge ab$, because there are no numbers between $y_0 + (k-1)b$ and $y_0 + kb$ that are divisible by $b$. But, we know that $(k-1)b < ab$, so this is a contradiction. Hence, $y_0 + kb = ab = x$ and the algorithm ends.

The same goes for case 2, and the case 3 says only that the algorithm may finish sooner.

You still need to show that the value that the algorithm computes is the least (common multiplier). This can be done by repeating what I did above, but using $m = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ instead of $ab$, thus showing that $x$ and $y$ cannot grow beyond it.

Comment: I agree with what youve done above. Great explanation!

Comment: I know this is 5 year+ old, but I have some trouble understanding $x-b \geq ab$. How do we know that b is smaller than a ? Because x was increased by a, but now if b is greater than a and we substract it from x, then $x-b$ could be smaller than $ab$, and so there wouldn't be a contradiction, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Poujh, it's a bit hard to remember what I was thinking then but I suspect that it's a typo, i.e., that I mixed up $a$ and $b$ in that expression, and that it should've been $x - a \ge ab$. Because $x$ is divisible by $a$, i.e., $x = pa$ for some nonnegative integer $p$, $x > ab$ would imply $x - a \ge ab$. The rest, as far as I see, holds as stated.